# javascript for loop using variable

Tags: javascript

Can I use variable to do the second `for` loop so it list out all data in GroupA1 and GroupB1.

Tried but fail.. anyone have idea how to make it work?

**for example**

```
function Loop(){
    var AllGroup=["GroupA1","GroupB1"]
    var GroupA1=["A1","A2"]
    var GroupB1=["B1","B2"]
    var Group=""

for(var i = 0; i < AllGroup.length; i++){
    Group=AllGroup[i]

    var SubGroup=""
    for(var x = 0; x < Group.length; x++){
        SubGroup=Group[x]
        alert(SubGroup);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: It is made more difficult than it needs to be because GroupA1 and GroupA2 are just vars.  If they were part of the same object then much easier, e.g. `var myGroups = { group1: ['A1', 'A2'], group2: ['B1', 'B2' }`.

Comment: You can do it with `eval()` ...

Comment: true, you could do it with eval, but there are 100 easier options.

Comment: also eval takes it out of scope so you'd have a hard time trying to return anything.

Comment: Bottom line: do not refer to variables via strings of their names. Refer to the variables themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully my sample code can help you to deal with your question

**For example**

```
<script>
    var GroupA1=["A1","A2"]
    var GroupB1=["B1","B2"]
    var Group=""
    var AllGroup = [GroupA1, GroupB1]    
for(var i = 0; i < AllGroup.length; i++){
    Group=AllGroup[i]

    var SubGroup=""
    for(var x = 0; x < Group.length; x++){
        SubGroup=Group[x]
        alert(SubGroup);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: please let me know if it can not handle your problem ,thanks

Comment: You re-defined the task, making it trivial.

Comment: Thanks Willie. It did help on my solution. I can enhance it more with this now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
function loop(){
 var GroupA1=["A1","A2"]
    var GroupB1=["B1","B2"]
var AllGroup=[GroupA1,GroupB1]

    var Group=""

    for(var i = 0; i < AllGroup.length; i++){
        Group=AllGroup[i]

        var SubGroup=""
        for(var x = 0; x < Group.length; x++){
            SubGroup=Group[x]
            alert(SubGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

Declare the arrays first then use them as objects in the next array.

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure I would recommend, which is more logical, instead of what you're using.

```
function Loop(){
    //The object AllGroups contains all the other groups
    var AllGroups = { 
        "GroupA1": ["A1","A2"],
        "GroupB1": ["B1","B2"]
    };

    for(var group in AllGroups){
            if(AllGroups.hasOwnProperty(group)){
                //Access each group in AllGroups
                for(var i = 0; i < AllGroups[group].length; i++){
                    console.log(AllGroups[group][i]); //A1, A2, B1, B2
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange code like this so that AllGroup is a collection containing GroupA1 and GroupB1:

```
function Loop() {
    var GroupA1=["A1", "A2"];
    var GroupB1=["B1", "B2"];
    var AllGroup=[GroupA1, GroupB1];
    var Group = null;

    for(var i = 0; i < AllGroup.length; i++){
        Group = AllGroup[i];

        var SubGroup = "";
        for(var x = 0; x < Group.length; x++){
            SubGroup = Group[x];
            alert(SubGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

Before you were referencing the strings "GroupA1" "GroupB1" not the actual data contained in the subgroups that you create.

Comment: Well when I was writing there was only 1 answer and it didn't have code. I wanted to show OP more detail into why he had his problem in addition to writing code :)